# How do i remove items from a list with specific rules in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

Basically i have a tupple of positions from an 8 x 8 chess board like so

```
chessboard = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(1,0),
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),   
(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),
(3,7),(3,8),(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8),(5,0),
(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(5,6),(5,7),(5,8),(6,0),(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),
(6,4),(6,5),(6,6),(6,7),(6,8),(7,0),(7,1),(7,2),(7,3),(7,4),(7,5),(7,6),
(7,7),(7,8),(8,0),(8,1),(8,2),(8,3),(8,4),(8,5),(8,6),(8,7),(8,8)]
```

I need to be able to place 8 queens on the chess board without each one being able to kill another one. I figured out a method to do this: if a queen is, for example, on (0,0) then no positions containing the same row or column is allowed, so I can remove (0,1), (0,2), (0,3) ... (x,y+1)  and (1,0) , (2,0), (3,0) ... (x+1,y) from the chessboard list. So if my queen is on (0,0), how can i remove all the tupples that are (x, y+1) , (x+1,y) , (x+1, y+1), (x-1,y-1) ? I'm leaning towards recursion, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: You can use `filter`.

Comment: FWIW, you can write that as `chessboard = [(x,y) | x <- [0..8], y <- [0..8]]`, or better yet, use a [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1/docs/Data-Set.html).

Comment: Btw for an 8x8 board the biggest index in a 0 indexed board is (7, 7), not (8, 8)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:filter). Note that the the first argument - the predicate - actually decides **what to keep**. Not what to remove (so if it says `True` that means it puts the element in the resulting list):

So in order to remove all values with `x = 0`, you can use

```
filter (\(x,_) -> x /= 0) chessboard
```

Or filter out all elements with `y` equal to `k`:

```
filtery k = filter (\(_,y) -> y /= k)
```

You can filter out all elements that attack a queen positioned at `(xq,yq)` with:

```
filterqueen :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
filterqueen (xq,yq) = filter noattack
    where noattack (x,y) = xq /= x && yq /= y && dx /= dy && dx /= -dy
              where dx = x-xq
                    dy = y-yq
```